# How are the utilities in GNU/Linux free and open-source if they're copied from UNIX?

Tags: linux, unix, open-source

If UNIX is proprietary software, how is it that all the basic UNIX utilities like grep, ls, etc. were copied in GNU/Linux with same functionality and syntax yet don't fall within the bounds of the UNIX license? Is it simply that the authors wrote their own implementation of these utilities without looking at the UNIX source that allowed them to claim it as their own creation?

Comment: Simple answer: none of those tools were copied. They were completely new implementations and actually typically are much more capable compared to the originals these days. All this is documented. If you want to look into it in more detail (which you should!) then you will find that the term "Linux" actually only refers to the operating systems kernel. All those utilities are _not_ part of Linux! The kernel and those utilities together form a distribution, a usable operating system. And most if those GNU utilities actually are older than the Linux kernel... Search for "BSD" and learn!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine a world where people use machines to talk to each other, buy things, search for things, read things... a place where the world is free and open!

Is that patentable?... it's a lovely idea and the only reason we're lucky enough to be living it is because it cannot be patented! Ideas and concepts are not patentable.

Linux might have copied some of the ideas, the process and implementation wasn't copied.